# nginx not able to connect to php-fpm socket

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, socket

I setup a system similar to the [tutorial here](http://vladgh.com/blog/varnish-nginx-and-php-533-ubuntu-1010).

I'm having issues with nginx connecting to the php5-fpm socket, but from what I can tell the permissions on the socket are correct... can you give me a hand?

```
2011/04/14 15:31:24 [crit] 13147#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 74.129.***.***, server: app.mydomain.com, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.socket:", host: "app.mydomain.com"

root@app0:/# ls -l /var/run/php5-fpm.socket
srw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 0 Apr 14 15:51 /var/run/php5-fpm.socket

root@app0:/# ps aux | grep fpm
root     13315  0.0  1.9 168276  4948 ?        Ss   15:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
www-data 13316  0.0  2.1 168672  5492 ?        S    15:51   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf

root@app0:/# ps aux | grep nginx
root     13341  0.0  0.4  33200  1036 ?        Ss   15:52   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data 13342  0.0  0.7  34008  1880 ?        S    15:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 13344  0.0  0.6  33680  1628 ?        S    15:52   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

I've got a few customizations to the configurations you provide, but it's largely the same.  Want to suggest a troubleshooting avenue?

Comment: Nevermind - I figured out a key configuration I was missing for nginx.

Comment: PLEASE tell what the heck was the problem...

Answer (score 7):

This is a gotcha that many tutorials omit. the php user should be the owner of the socket. So you want to make sure that

```
chown www-data:www-data /var/run/php5-fpm.socket
```

Comment: And how do I persist this change? Every time `php5-fpm` is reloaded it creates socket with root as an owner.

Comment: TCP is a better approach anyways, for future Googlers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what caused this exactly, probably some changes in PHP code, but I've found a way to fix this:

1) Open your pool configuration as root, mine is in: `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`

2) Add the following lines:

- `listen.owner = www-data`
- `listen.group = www-data`

Here's the [complete documentation](http://www.php.net//manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) for all config parameters.

3) Restart PHP FPM: `sudo service php5-fpm restart`

It should re-create socket file with proper user and group:

**ls -lah /var/run/ | grep php**:

`-rw-r--r--  1 root       root          4 Jun 24 18:19 php5-fpm.pid
srw-rw----  1 www-data   www-data      0 Jun 24 18:19 php5-fpm.sock`

I hope it will help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  On my dev laptop (MacOS) I want to run everything in my own account, to keep it all simple.  The socket i-node is owned by my own account.

I just had to comment out listen.owner and listen.group in www.conf.

I start everything in my own account with "brew services start --all".

In www.conf, 'user' is still set to '_www'.  Socket is still owned by myself.  Not sure why this doesn't cause an error.